# php - SoapClient only send First Parameter

Tags: php, web, soap

so i want to ask about php SoapClient class. I have a running soap service using java that receive 2 parameter String name and String year. This is my php code

```
<?php
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost:9000/getBook?wsdl');
echo $soapClient->getBook("manifesto", "1999");
```

**getBook will return name+year;**

When I run that code on web, I always get **manifestonull**. It seems that my Java SOAP service didn't receive the year parameter.

But, when I try to use this piece of code on php interactive shell, I got **manifesto1999** (My java soap service receive the second params!!)

Does anyone know how to fix this error? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

turn out, you need to set soap version to SOAP_1_1

```
$options = array(
  'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1
);
```

It works for me